# Sitecore check if an item has a delta with presentation details standard template

Tags: components, sitecore

We have a lot of products that are stored as a Sitecore item.
Many of them use the presentation details defined on the Standard Values of the product template.

Now I would like the check for each product, if the presentation details is the same as the standard values.

And if they are not the same as in the standard values, I need to see the delta.

Someone an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can query all items and look at the "__renderings" field and come the value of it to the same field on the standard values. This field is the XML that stores the presentation settings. Any pages that have a value that doesn't match the standard values has been changed.